# how to get posts by id in redux selector

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to retrieve all posts by according to userId. I'm unsure how to get the logic to work, where its resuable through out the whole application.

I want be able to call the selector `getUserPosts` , and be able to iterated it on user profile page, how would i do this ?

this is what i have

**selectors**

```
export const getPosts = () => // this gets all posts
    createSelector(
        postSelector,
        (state) => state.posts,
    );
export const getUserPosts = () =>  // how i do i get all posts based on user id i pass state here 
    createSelector(
        postSelector,
        (state) => state.posts.filter((user) => user.userId === state.id)
    )
```

**container**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStructuredSelector } from "reselect";
import Profile from "./../components/Profile/Profile"
import { getUserPosts } from "./../selectors/selectors";
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    userPosts: getUserPosts()
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    null,
)(Profile);
```

**reducer**

```
import produce from "immer";
import * as types from "../actionTypes/postActionTypes";
import { validation } from '../utils';
export interface postState {
  posts: any[];
  postPage: any;
  error: any;
  titleError: any;
  bodyError: any;
  title: string
  postContent: string

}

const initialState: postState = {
  posts: [],
  postPage: {},
  titleError: null,
  bodyError: null,
  title: "",
  postContent: "",
  error: null
};

const postReducer = (state = initialState, action: any): postState =>
  produce(state, (draft) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case types.GET_POSTS_SUCCESS:
        draft.posts = action.payload;
        return;
    }
  });

export default postReducer;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pass a user id into your selector function as a parameter

```
export const getUserPosts = (state, userId) => 
  createSelector(
    postSelector,
    state => state.posts.filter(user => user.userId === userId)
  )
```

And leverage the useSelector hook in react-redux. So in the component you want to display them in, assuming you have a user id as a prop

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getUserPosts } from "./../selectors/selectors"

const Profile = props => {
  const { userId } = props
  const posts = useSelector(state => getUserPosts(state, userId)
}
```

Comment: how will i add this logic to the container component, or could i access selector directly on component ?

Comment: You can access it directly on the component.